# Unexpected behaviour of cmd-period in JavaFX KeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx, cmd, keyevent

I am listening for KeyEvents using the following code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sandpit extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> System.out.println(e.getCode()));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(0));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am running this code on a Mac (OS X 10.10.4) with Java 8.

When I enter the key combination Command-Period (cmd-.), i.e., hold down the command key and enter the period key, I get the following output:

```
COMMAND
PERIOD
A
```

I have no idea where this "A" KeyEvent is coming from. Every other key combination I have tried works as expected.

Can anyone explain this and suggest how to get rid of it?

Alternative keywords: cmd-period command-period cmd-. command-.

Comment: I cannot replicate this, there is no A output on my machine when I run your app and hit CMD+PERIOD.  Test system: 2012 Macbook Air, OS 10.9.5, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-ea-b13)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some feedback from a Windows 7 user (no Command key of course, but we use CTRL instead). All combinations CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, WINDOWS etc with PERIOD work as expected. So I'm guessing that the Mac COMMAND key does something funny like adding that character. In fact if your check your Mac keyboard sequences, you'll see that a Mac treats COMMAND PERIOD as an ESCape. While this doesn't explain the 'A' in my book, I think that's where you'll need to concentrate.